# AWS PHP SDK upload file to S3 confusing errors

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

Ok, so I have tried several methods of getting a file to upload to my S3 account. Finally found myself getting somewhere and BOOM - confusing documentation and strange error messages which appear to contradict themselves.

Ok, to start with I am not using composer or anything like that, I am doing this the old fashioned way:

```
require '/path/to/aws-autoload.php';
```

Now this loads correctly, and I have trimmed down the autoload to only use Common and S3 classes - don't need everything!

Next up I load the S3 Client and Credentials:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;
```

Now the code to start the magic happening:

```
$file = '/path/to/' . $filename;
$credentials = new Credentials('KEY', 'SECRET KEY');
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array('credentials' => $credentials));

try{
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'sub.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com',
    'Body'   => fopen($file, 'r'),
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
));
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
     $result = array(
         'ok' => false,
         'descr' => 'There was an error uploading the file to S3 : ' . $filename
     );
}
```

The issue I seem to be having is with the 'Bucket' itself.

When I format the Bucket as **sub.domain.com** I get the following message back from the AWS API:

> AWS Error Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint: "sub.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com".

Now when I change the 'Bucket' to match the above like so : **sub.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com**

I get the following error message :

> AWS Error Message: The specified bucket does not exist

Am I doing something wrong? Is something missing? Unfortunately the AWS Documentation is not quite up to scratch. The API seems to be contradicting itself at the moment. I know all the keys are correct, and all permissions are correct. It went from 301 - Redirect to 404 - Not Found from its own advice.

Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I am going in circles a little here!

Comment: Isn't just the `sub.domain` part used as an example? I think you should change this value to whatever you named your bucket in the first place.

Comment: I have already done this, I set this to **sub.domain**  when posting on here to make this more generic and not give away the site I work for. Also The **KEY** and **SECRET KEY** are set to the correct values

Comment: Have you tried accessing your bucket using a `path-style URL` like `http://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>`?

Comment: Yep, same result : `<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><Bucket>sub.domain.com</Bucket><Endpoint>sub.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>`

Comment: If I go to **sub.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com** I get a public listing of the contents of this bucket. However the SDK kicks up a fuss still.

Comment: Have you checked so you don't use an invalid region in your url, `bucket.us-west-2.s3.amazoneaws.com` over `bucket.us-east-1.s3.amazoneaws.com`

Comment: Try using the php s3 client to check so the name of your bucket is valid for an S3 bucket, `isValidBucketName($bucketName);`, I'm thinking that the problem might be the format of the name of the bucket.

Comment: Check so you bucket name is valid http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html as an DNS compatible Amazon S3 bucket

Comment: If I use a region in my URL I get this error : **The specified bucket does not exist** same as I get in the SDK for the none region specific bucket name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things to double check.

1. If the bucket was created in a certain region (e.g., us-west-2), instantiate the `S3Client` with that region `[..., 'region' => 'us-west-2', ...]`.
2. The `'Bucket'` parameter should be set to exactly what your bucket is named (e.g., if your bucket is named "sub.domain.com", then the `'Bucket'` parameter should be set to `'sub.domain.com'`). Do not include the region or "s3.amazonaws.com" in the `'Bucket'` parameter (i.e., bucket != endpoint). The SDK automatically determines the endpoint (based on the client's region and provided bucket name) and adjusts the URL for path-style if needed.
3. The **PutObject** operation requires the `'Key'` parameter, which is not present in the code sample above.